# Jq help to parse json data

Tags: jquery, json, jq

I have below json data. Need help in parsing it.

```
{
  "name": "Amit",
  "Subject": {
    "Maths": {
      "Score": 10,
      "ttl": 480
    },
    "Science": {
      "Score": 20,
      "ttl": 480
    }
  }
}
```

I need output like below. It could be possible that Subject tag is missing so that record should be skipped.

```
Amit,Maths,10
Amit,Science,20
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the levels, and collect what you want to print in variables. Use `? // empty` on elements to skip if inexistent, and `keys_unsorted` to get a list of field names. Finally, put all your items in an array, and use `join` to concatenate with a separator.

```sh
jq -r '
  .name as $name | .Subject? // empty | keys_unsorted[] as $key
  | [$name, $key, .[$key].Score] | join(",")
'
```

```json
Amit,Maths,10
Amit,Science,20
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ppl-DqWEx-T)